# For a4j:jsFunction, does reRender or oncomplete happen first?

Tags: javascript, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a jsFunction that I am running, and would like javascript to be performed after re-rendering is finished.  I'm guessing that the javascript in "oncomplete" is called -after- re-rendering takes place, but don't know for sure.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct, oncomplete happens after rending is done. Here is more info on a4j:jsFunction: http://mkblog.exadel.com/ria/richfaces-ria/using-richfaces-a4jjsfunction-sending-an-ajax-request-from-any-javascript/.